# How to move data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a command button that will allow me to move data to another sheet and deleting the data from the initial sheet. I am unable to figure this out and it will only copy the data rather than moving it as a whole.

I tried to specify the range of what cells I would like to move. It works however, I want to be able to move data from the cell I click rather than just having specified cells.

```
     whichSheet = InputBox("In which sheet do you wish to enter data? Specify 
     sheet number as Sheet2 & Sheet3 only.", "Sheet Number")

     If whichSheet = "" Then
         MsgBox "You didn't specify a sheet!"
         Exit Sub
     End If

     Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate

     Dim lastrow
     lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     lastrow = lastrow + 1
     Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1

     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lastrow), 
         Cells(lastrow, 1)) > 1 Then
         MsgBox "Duplicate data! Only unique IDs allowed", vbCritical, "Remove Data"
         Cells(lastrow, 1) = “”
     ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lastrow), 
         Cells(lastrow, 1)) = 1 Then
         answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add the record?", vbYesNo + 
         vbQuestion, "Add Record")
         If answer = vbYes Then
            Cells(lastrow, 1) = txtMRN.Text
            Cells(lastrow, 2) = txtLastname.Text
            Cells(lastrow, 3) = txtFirstname.Text
                If Len(Range("D12")) <> 0 Then
                    Sheet2.Cells(erw, 1) = CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
                    Sheet2.Cells(erw, 2) = CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
                    Sheet2.Cells(erw, 3) = CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1    
                    CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""
                    CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""
                    CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""
                End If
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In your code, what is the range of cells in question?

Comment: I don't want to have a specified range, I want to be able to click a cell and transfer that information into another sheet.

Comment: Said in another way - there is a lot of code shared here, and not all of it seems relevant to what you want to do. What is the relevant portion?

Comment: If Len(Range("D12")) <> 0 Then
Sheet2.Cells(erw, 1) = CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
Sheet2.Cells(erw, 2) = CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
Sheet2.Cells(erw, 3) = CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""
CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""
CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""
End If

Comment: What is `CurrentRegion`? `CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = ""` looks off, and I doubt you need 3 instances of the same line.

Comment: CurrentRegion is for the row of cells I want to transfer. I wanted to input a code that would transfer data on that row into another sheet, that is why I used CurrentRegion.

Comment: Yes, but it is [`Range.CurrentRegion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion), not just a standalone `CurrentRegion` - what is the `Range`? And you can't set a `Rows.Count` equal to `""`. A count is a number. And I'm not even sure why you're using `Rows.Count`.

Comment: I initially had this code:

Comment: erw = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
erw = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

If Len(Range("A8")) <> 0 Then
    Sheet2.Cells(erw, 1) = Range("A8")
    Sheet2.Cells(erw, 2) = Range("B8")
    Sheet2.Cells(erw, 3) = Range("C8")
    
    Range("A8") = ""
    Range("B8") = ""
    Range("C8") = ""

Comment: It works like this perfectly fine but It only specifies moving data from that current range, that is what I don't want and what I need help on.

Comment: I'd suggest that you replace all the code currently in your question with that original code.

Comment: Your question and sample is very confusing. Please provide more context. What are you actually trying to do.